# JavaScript tabbed content without using jquery

Tags: javascript

ok i know how to create tabbed content in `jquery`, but i want to create it in pure `JavaScript`
and i dont know how to start please someone help me 
this is the basic html structure

```
<html>
<head>
<title> my tabbed content </title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tab">
<h3>tab 1</h3>
<div id="content1">
<p>some content </p>
</div>
<h3>tab 2</h3>
<div id="content2">
<p>some content </p>
<!-- and so on -->
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: yeah but it wont work

Comment: Can you post the tried JS?

Comment: i want to just get the idea if u can tell me pls

Comment: or any site where i can learn it

Comment: Okey to have an idea, h3 and div must have the same proprety "data-index" for exemple, by clicking on h3 (that have proprety data-index="2") , it hide all div (having class name) and show div with data-index=2

Comment: If you want to get the idea, use google (since that has been discussed multiple times) or look at existing code (since they already have done it where you can take a peek). But overall, this does not look like you invested much time in researching...

Comment: i did my researching but i only get results in jquery not in javascript thats why i came here to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one here will give you an answer with code if you did not put an effort to do it yourself. Showing some basic HTML code with a few divs will not work either.

You want an idea, so if I understand your question here is an example concept:

- create and style a few divs so that they look like tabs,
- those divs can either constitute of all needed elements like: content, framing and upper caption that is also functioning as button to select particular div as active. You may as well decouple it and treat e.g. those buttons separately,
- add basic JavaScript code bound to captioned parts of tabs that will make their content visible or not, on the other hand you may also stack them and manipulate their z-index property